# NGINX and UWSGI not communicating

Tags: django, sockets, nginx, uwsgi

I'm very new to NGINX, or setting up a server in general. I'm going through the tutorial http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html with a website I'm trying to set up. I'm getting to the point in the tutorial where you use sockets, however, I can't get the socket to work. nginx.conf looks like this.

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/althor/projects/Freebooks/freebooks.sock; # for a file socket
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 10.0.0.130; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/althor/projects/FreeBooks/media;  # your Django project's media                   files - amend as required  
}

location /static {
   alias /home/althor/projects/FreeBooks/static; # your Django project's static files -          amend as required
}

# Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include     /home/althor/projects/FreeBooks/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
}
```

}

The command i'm doing is this:

```
uwsgi --socket freebooks.sock --module FreeBooks.wsgi --chmod-socket=664
```

My File structure looks like this

-home
    -projects
         -FreeBooks
              freebooks_nginx.conf
              freebooks.sock=
             -FreeBooks
                  wsgi

I'm not getting any type of error. When I go to 10.0.0.130, all I get is the welcome to nginx thing, same for 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1. Except when I got to port 8000 where I get a bad nginx gateway. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you got the answer, if so please let me know how did you solved it, Because i am having the same problem

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to pick an answer. The issue was that nginx didn't have permission to write to the socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out be a permissions issue. NGINX didn't have permission to write to the socket.

Answer (score 0):

remove your "upstream django" line and replace your uwsgi_pass line with
uwsgi_pass unix:///home/althor/projects/Freebooks/freebooks.sock;

so that your file looks like

```
server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name 10.0.0.130; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /media  {
        alias /home/althor/projects/FreeBooks/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/althor/projects/FreeBooks/static;
    }

    location / {
        include /home/althor/projects/FreeBooks/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  unix:///home/althor/projects/Freebooks/freebooks.sock;
    }
}
```

Also make sure the socket file actually gets created when you run uwsgi command and that it is readable by the user running nginx (the properties are right but does the user have access to the full path?)

Comment: How to make user to access full path